# Warning on uploading site from localhost to live server

Tags: wordpress

Warning: file_put_contents(/home/dodafric/public_html/wp-content/uploads/kallyas-builder/cache/889-layout.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/dodafric/public_html/wp-content/themes/kallyas/framework/pagebuilder/scripts-manager.php on line 247

See my website ... dodafricmradi.com

Comment: your theme is purchasable ?

Comment: remove kallyas-builder plugin and that try again

Comment: http://support.hogash.com/support/topic/kallyas-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-css-on-a-non-object/

Comment: removing page builder didn't work